# c# launch program when user wants to access a folder/file

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on folder/file lock program. Lets say my program knows which folders/files were locked, I want my program to launch (wpf window opens and asks for password) when user wants to access locked folder/file ( I want this possibility only on locked folders). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This sounds a whole lot like you're trying to write some sort of malware...

Comment: I am not trying to, I just want such functionality.

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. There is several ways. You could write a service that starts a program when locked folders are clicked. You could probably also write a program, that runs in the processline and are hidden normally. But pops up when a locked folder is clicked.

The big question is, why would you want to do that? Sounds like you're trying to write malware.